# Eclipse SVN : how to use Compare With ... branch?

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge, branching-and-merging

In Eclipse with SVN, I would like to see which changes (line by line!) are done in another branch (or trunk) and then decide for each changed file if I want to keep my working copy version or the changed file.

I think this is the way it should work, but apparently it doesn't in SVN/Eclipse. I tried the merge functions, and I kept getting tree conflicts, trunk out of date errors, etc. Even with a very simple project with only 2 files in it, everything goes wrong. The automated merge thing just doesn't work for me ! You have absolutely no control of what is actually going to happen to your files, and end up with a totally ruined working copy, in the case of conflicts.  Which you have to fix AFTER the merge!

I do like the Compare With-function to compare branches with each other though. But I couldn't find any way to practically use this to update changed files. All I get is a nice treeview with all changed files, and the possibility to compare the actual changes, but no way of marking the changes as merged!

It seems what I want is just not possible with Compare With ?
Is there NO other tool at all then where you have *total* control of your merges ?  Maybe I should change to GIT or Mercurial?!

Any idea's about the subject are welcome...

***UPDATE***:

Found these alternative SVN clients myself, both look promising for dealing with changes in different branches:

http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/

https://www.smartsvn.com/

Comment: Have you tried the "Team Synchronization" perspective (select Team->Synchronize with Repository on the project to be checked)?

Comment: I think you can only Synchronize with the repository/branch that the working copy is connected with. Not with another branch...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such nice gui. There is a manual way, but it's not so easy and simple.

I don't Eclipse here, but I'll try to use my memory.

You can use the history view to see which commits were made on a branch. Just drag the branch from svn repositories view to history view. It will show the branch history.

Then you can select two commits (starting and ending) you want to make a diff from. Then you get a window where you can choose the graphical gui comparison or output to diff file. When you get the diff you can apply it to the workspace using package explorer and team menu.